# What does After and Requires label means in Service file?

Tags: linux, docker

This is docker.service file, and I want to know what does "After" label in [Unit] service do?

```
cd /usr/lib/systemd/system
```

.

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket
Requires=flanneld.service
After=flanneld.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/flanneld
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --bip=${FLANNEL_SUBNET}
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The **After** label here means, delay the start of the Docker service defined in this unit, until the unit **flanneld.service** is started. For more infomation take a look at [systemd unit documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20150324001109/http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora20/man5/systemd.unit.5.html)